# How to process SVG with namespace in R?

Tags: r, xml, svg

I have code:

```
transformXML <- function(xml, fn) {
  x <- xml2::read_xml(xml)
  fn(x)
  tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".xml")
  xml2::write_xml(x, tmp, options = "format")
  paste(unlist(readLines(tmp)), collapse='\n')
}

fname <- "inst/shiny/test.svg"

svg <- readChar(fname, file.info(fname)$size)

## move text that is in top of the plot tot the left
svg <- transformXML(svg, function(xml) {
    text.nodes <- xml2::xml_find_all(xml, ".//text")
    for (text in text.nodes) {
        if (as.double(xml2::xml_attr(text, 'y')) < 60) {
            xml2::xml_set_attr(text, 'x', '0')
        }
    }
})
message(svg)
```

When I have SVG like this:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 0 1319.34 500.00'>
```

But it can't find anything in the SVG. It always returns 0 nodes, even If I use `//svg` XPath.

If I remove `xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'` it works fine, How can I use default namespace in XML and process the file with R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the problem is the different namespace the svg elements are in. Take a look here : https://www.inflectra.com/support/knowledgebase/kb503.aspx how to select those elements.

Comment: This looks like a bug in XPath spec or libxml library. it seems that this works `xml2::xml_find_all(xml, "//*[name()='text']")`

Comment: @jcubic: Do you have a url to better understand your remark?  I suppose you mean that the XPath ".//text" should give the same result as "//*[name()='text']" .  There is however a small difference in that ".//text" starts with a dot, meaning the current context. "//*[name()='text']" will find from root. But to be honest I have no knowledge about R...

Comment: This is a basic XPath and has nothing to do with the R. I think that this is an issue with libxml2. The R package is just the wrapper over that library. I think for me `.//` and `//` work the same. It finds all elements on the page, maybe because I'm using a root node as starting point. Maybe it will work differently when I start with a node deeper in the tree.